# I am facing an error while executing testcase in HP ALM using PAF

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

Error found in the console

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In config.properties file , we have to set  ALM_TEMPLATE_UPDATED=true
the testcase will be executed Without any error.